# Can anyone review the following code of solution of UVa 10038?

Tags: c++

I am currently solving the [UVa Problem no. 10038](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/100/10038.pdf). So, to debug my code I went to [uDebug](https://udebug.com/UVa/10038). And found that my code was almost complete but with some exceptions.

I want the following code to reviewed. Any suggestions for editting can be helpful.

I have tried using while loop(at the near end of code) instead of the if statement but that freezes the input.

```cpp
/*#include <iostream>, <vector>, <algorithm>, <functional>*/

int main(){
/*Declaring everything required*/
    int n, num, diff;
    bool is_jolly;
    vector<int> numbers, differences;

    while(cin >> n){
        /*Deleting all elements before working with them*/
        numbers.clear();
        differences.clear();

/*A sequence of single number is always JOLLY*/

            /*Taking in all the numbers*/
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                cin >> num;
                numbers.push_back(num);
            }

            /*Calculating the absolute value of those*/
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
                diff = abs(numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1]);
                differences.push_back(diff);
            }

            /*Sorting the differences in descending order*/
            if(differences.size() > 1){
                sort(differences.begin(), differences.end(), greater<int>());
            }

            /*Creating a iterator for checking if the value reached one through n - 1*/
            int k = n - 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < differences.size(); i++){
                if(differences[i] == k){/*Tried the while loop here*/
                    is_jolly = true;/*<-----This is where the problem is. If the difference at first is equal to k then it will not check again. I want it to check as long as the loop runs*/
                }else{
                    is_jolly = false;
                }
            k--;
            }
/*if is_jolly is true will print "Jolly" else "Not jolly"*/

        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

The input is

```
1 2000
5 1 4 2 -1 6
2 1999 1998
4 1 4 2 3
4 1 3 2 -2 <---- Here I am getting Jolly instead of Not Jolly
4 1 4 3 5
4 1 2 5 7
3 4 1 3
4 1 4 2 3
4 1 2 3 6 <--- Here I am getting Jolly instead of Not Jolly
2 1 3
1 1
```

Everything else works as expected.

Comment: If it's working example to be reviewed, then [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be better place, but it seems you just need debugging help here?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Its c++14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this loop like this.

If at any moment, any *differences[i]* is not equal to *k* then it is **not** *jolly*. Otherwise, it is *jolly*. So we will check if at any moment *difference[i]* is **not** equal to k then *is_jolly* is **false**.

```
is_jolly = true; // suppose the answer is true
for(int i = 0; i < differences.size(); i++){
     if(differences[i] != k){    // if at any time this value is not k then answer is false.
          is_jolly = false;
          break;
     }
     k--;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. *Why* is it a solution to the problem?

Comment: If at any moment, any differences[i] is not equal to k then it is not jolly. Otherwise, it is jolly. So we will check if at any moment difference[i] is not equal to k then is_jolly is false.